# Trying to find my public ipv6 address for ubuntu server and godaddy

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, godaddy, ifconfig

I have just set up ubuntu server, and I cant figure out this stupid xfinity router/modem. So what I've managed to do is set a static ipv6 on ubuntu server

```
iface enp4s0 inet6 static
address 2601:407:8402:38bc:0000:0000:0000:0010
netmask 64
gateway 2601:407:8402:38bc:0000:0000:0000:0001
```

Then on godaddy I set AAAA (IPv6 Host) to

```
2601:407:8402:38bc::10
```

I have opened up ports 80 & 3306, and on my browser I can navigate to my website, but when I try from my phone (with wifi off) I am unable to navigate to my domain and my ip(v6)

```
[2601:407:8402:38bc::10]
```

Another route I have already tried is disabling ipv6 altogether but for some reason even with ports open and canyouseeme able to see my normal ip / ports, I can not able to access my server, I have never had this type of problem with any other router/modem so the problem probably lays with that.

I figure there has to be a way to get this all set up with ipv6 although the way ipv6 is, it just confuses me. Is there anyway I can get my ipv6 address and use it for my domain on godaddy.

This is my ifconfig

```
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:60:77:fa:98:6b
      inet addr:10.0.0.66  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::3a60:77ff:fefa:986b/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2601:407:8402:38bc::10/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:43574 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:34340 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:27639502 (27.6 MB)  TX bytes:16077266 (16.0 MB)
```

Or maybe I already did everything right and the DNS just needs to update...

Domain that should load http://dirtrif.com

Comment: from the server, can you get to `ipv6.icanhazip.com`

Comment: its a ubuntu server i have physical access to but I dont know how to browse the web on it I use putty theres no gui

Comment: just found and installed ELinks (terminal browser that only loads text) let me see if I can figure this out

Comment: Why have you set a manual IPv6 address? This is not the normal way to set up IPv6 on Comcast.

Comment: I have no clue, tried the normal way disabling ipv6 in my network and using my normal ip, but I still could not load my ip (apache) so i went the ipv6 route and have no idea how to get it going.  couldnt find any tuts that helped either.  Know of any?

Comment: if i go to canyouseeme, it shows my normal ip, and shows 80 is visable.  No matter what I do though I can not navigate to my ip unless I use ipv6

Comment: Where did you get the IPv6 network? Are you sure that is the correct gateway address? You could always try the router anycast address, which is the network address. All addresses in a network can be used for a host, but the all-zeroes host address is reserved for the router anycast address, and all routers should respond to it.

Comment: honestly this is all new to me (ipv6) and all I did was follow this tutorial https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-ipv6-networking-configuration/ and I chaged the numbers because in my router when I open a port there were 4 filled boxes with charecters I couldnt change 2601 407 8402 38bc so I kind of just went with it and my internet still worked on my server so I thought I had it, from a loacl pc i can goto [2601:407:8402:38bc::10] and it loads just fine, Just cant from a device not on my network thats where the problem is

Comment: @JacobEvans well that browser thing I found doesnt support ipv6 so it wont even load that site nor a couple others I tried, The ones I did manage to load only show my ip address which is just a bust cause some reason I cant get through with my normal IP, Thank you though

Comment: just a note to any of you I'd be more than happy to TeamViewer if anyone thinks they can help and get a more hands on approach of what I have going on

Comment: reconfigure you ipv6 for autoconfigure, type `curl ipv6.icanhazip.com`

Comment: @JacobEvans thanks now at least I have the full ipv6 address, one step closer =)

Comment: great,  what's the output of `ip addr`

Comment: @JacobEvans http://pastebin.com/GMyrrLcD

Answer (score 1):

use autoconfigure and then set a secondary address to use with your apache config

fist 4 sections are your delegated prefix.

last 4 sections are yours to set (64bit network/64 bit host)

add this after your iface config

```
up /sbin/ipconfig enp4s0 inet6 add  2601:407:8402:38bc::10/64
```

this doesn't mean comcast isn't going to filter the ports, but it should work locally.

remember you have public or registered ip addresses, but that doesn't mean you don't have a firewall.  you may need to open ports there as well.

these addresses are not static,  but typical lifetime for ipv6 prefix delegation is lifetime.

Comment: updated for ubuntu

Comment: I have allowed the ports through the router and through the firewall and even disabled the firewall.  My complete network/interfaces looks like http://pastebin.com/WxvJdmmp and I'm opening my ports like http://imgur.com/a/hkdfN should i change those to the ipv6 one and only put 10 in the last box?

Comment: you aren't port forwarding,  you want to open the firewall for that IP, port forwarding maps the router v6 to the internal server you specified

Comment: and the up sbin command is one line

Comment: so the up... needs to go right after iface enp4s0 inet6 auto?

Comment: sorry this is all new to me, I think I may just go get another router so I dont even have to bother with ipv6, I dont see why I cant just use my ipv4 =/ it just wont go thru

Comment: I'm not convinced port 80 is an option on comcast residential service

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49580/discussion-between-your-mom-and-jacob-evans).

Comment: chat doesn't work on mobile, and I'm done tonight

Comment: ok thanks i did manage to switch the port on everything and open it, works with ipv4 now :) just dont know how to go about defining a different port on godaddy now

Comment: you can't unless you have a record redirect to another with the custom port (forwarding with mask)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to set a manual ipv6 address - you just need to set up your router for SLAAC or stateless connections, and set your ubuntu box for it. While I'm not on comcast, my ISP uses the same method and it just works automatically.

Since ipv6 seems to work on other systems, you simply need to replace your static address stanza with `iface enp4s0 inet6 auto` bring the interface up and down, and check and test that IP. `ping -6 google.com` should work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you could be connecting using your browser over wifi and unable to connect using your mobile phone data is probably because your mobile phone is using a different ISP and your wifi router has a different ISP. Not all ISP's have IPV6 support activated yet. Ive checked with my mobile operator and confirmed that they do not support IPV6 yet. Thats what you need to check first before playing around with settings. Here is a link about this https://test-ipv6.com/faq_no_ipv6.html
You can also check if you have IPV6 supported by your mobile operator using the same site at https://test-ipv6.com